# Greasemonkey get google search autocomplete results

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation, greasemonkey

I'm trying to have the autocomplete suggestions from Google search (e.g. when we press 'a' and we get a list of the suggested results), and achieve that through the script (This is actually a script for another website, but I put Google since this is publicly accessible).

The problem is that the script completes the input with random letters, but we get no suggestions. Here's my script: (You can use it on Greasemonkey, and check the result on google.com)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Google Test
// @version  1
// @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js
// @match https://*.google.com/*
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

console.log('Google script started');

function performSearch() {
    const customKeyCode = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 60);
    
    // I use .gLFyf.gsfi for the selector, you can inspect your google.com in case class is different in your case
    $('input.gLFyf.gsfi').each(function(i) {
            $(this).attr("autocomplete","on");
            $(this).blur();
            $(this).focus();
            $(this).trigger($.Event("keydown", {keyCode: customKeyCode}));
            $(this).val(String.fromCharCode(customKeyCode));
            $(this).trigger($.Event("keypress", {keyCode: customKeyCode}));
            $(this).trigger($.Event("keyup", {keyCode: customKeyCode}));
            $(this).keypress();
    });

    console.log('filled ');
}

// initial calls
setInterval(() => {
    performSearch();
}, 2000);
```

If anyone could provide info why this is not triggering the autocomplete on Google, I would be more than grateful :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I need to add a click to the parent element. Here's the final script in case someone will need a similar solution in the future:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Google Test
// @version  1
// @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js
// @match https://*.google.com/*
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

console.log('Google script started');


function performSearch() {
    const customKeyCode = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 60);
    
    // I use .gLFyf.gsfi for the selector, you can inspect your google.com in case class is different in your case
    $('input.gLFyf.gsfi').each(function(i) {
            $(this).attr("autocomplete","on");
            $(this).blur();
            $(this).focus();
            $(this).trigger($.Event("keydown", {keyCode: customKeyCode}));
            $(this).val(String.fromCharCode(customKeyCode));
            $(this).trigger($.Event("keypress", {keyCode: customKeyCode}));
            $(this).trigger($.Event("keyup", {keyCode: customKeyCode}));
                $(this).parent().trigger('click');
    });

    console.log('filled ');
}

// initial calls
setInterval(() => {
    performSearch();
}, 2000);
```